# PHP Regex: allowed no more 3 digits but any count for another chars

Tags: php, regex

I need to modify the exp:

```
/^[-\p{L}\d]+$/u
```

The purpose is to allow maximum 3 digits in whole string, but letter chars and dashes should be allowed without quantity restrictions. No matters where digits are located within string. For instance:

```
test345  //this should match
345te-st  //this should match
3454dtest  //this shouldn\'t match
```

I have already tried some patterns, but is don't work properly:

```
/^[-\p{L}\d{0,3}]+$/u
/^[-\p{L}]+[\d]{0,3}+$/u
/^([-\p{L}]+)([\d]+){0,3}$/u
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patterns that you tried don't work properly matching max 3 digits anywhere in the string because between the start and end anchors:

- This notation is fully in a character class `[-\p{L}\d{0,3}]+` which matches repeating 1+ times any of the listed characters  between `[...]` (So there is no digit limit due to the `+`)
- This notation `[-\p{L}]+[\d]{0,3}+` matches 1+ times `[-\p{L}]` followed by 0-3 consecutive digits (So the digits can not be at the start for example)
- This notation `([-\p{L}]+)([\d]+){0,3}` uses 2 capture groups, but the order here is also 1+ times `[-\p{L}]` and 0-3 consecutive digits (only here is the capture group repeated)

If empty strings are also allowed:

```
^(?:[\p{L}-]*\d){0,3}[\p{L}-]*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:[\p{L}-]*\d){0,3}` Match 0-3 times optional repetitions of `[\p{L}-]` and a single digit
- `[\p{L}-]*` Match optional repetitions of `[\p{L}-]` at the end
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q8LLFf/1)

Else you can assert that the string is not empty using `(?!$)`

```
^(?!$)(?:[\p{L}-]*\d){0,3}[\p{L}-]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y4tqQ1/1)